# Which libraries must be linked with protocol-buffers generated C++ code

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have the mytest.cc and mytest.h output from a mytest.proto file, but I can't find any reference on to how to compile a object using g++ for this.  (the .proto is fine as I got it working with Python)

g++ mytest.cc -l???????

what libraries to include?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you may need to link to libprotobuf

```
g++ mytest.cc -lprotobuf -o mytest
```

Comment: Yup, that's all you need library-wise... although if you want it to actually DO anything, you'll need more code.

Comment: Ok, that's what I have been doing. I am guessing the C libraries didn't get installed (the python portion had a problem with the x86_64 arch) or were installed to some whacked out place. Thanks!